# LINQ example code from microsoft...

Tags: linq

Can anyone explain the following LINQ example code from microsoft...

I am having trouble understanding the (**digit, index**) part of the lambda expression:

```
public void Linq5()
{
    string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

    var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);

    Console.WriteLine("Short digits:");
    foreach (var d in shortDigits)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The word {0} is shorter than its value.", d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check the documentation for Where? It is [trivially found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx). Did something about it not make sense?

Comment: I did check the documentation... but I didn't understand how 
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
 this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)

becomes

IEnumerable<int> query =
                numbers.Where((number, index) => number <= index * 10);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am having trouble understanding the (digit, index) part of the lambda expression:

There are two overloads to `Where`. One takes a predicate mapping instances of the sequence type to `bool`, and the other takes a predicate mapping pairs of (instance of the sequence type, index in the sequence)  to bool. This is so you can say things like

```
sequence.Where((x, index) => index % 2 == 0 && x.Length > 5))
```

That is: give me all the items in the sequence with even index and length more than 5.

In this example:

```
digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);
```

we are saying: give me all the items in the sequence with item length less than its position in the sequence, i.e., all the digits whose length is shorter than the value it represents.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the lambda expression's parameters.

The compiler will infer their types based on the delegate that the lambda is being used as.
In this case, that's `Func<T, int, bool>` from the `Where()` overload.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda expression is a shortcut to writing the psedocode:

```
bool FunctionWithNoName(string digit, int index)
{
 return (digit.Length < index);
}
```

Comment: In which case, is index already defined?  I guess if I used foo here this would not work.

Comment: Nope, index is just the name of the argument for the function. The term index is arbitrary here, you could use anything, as you would with any function.

Comment: This has clicked into place!  Thanks for the help... I just struggle with the MSDN website... I can't make sense of this...

public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
 this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
 Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate
)